# Two identical programs, only one compiles (java7)

Tags: java, copy, paste

While studying from the pdf presentation of the lesson, i usually try and compile a lot of the examples given, often i rewrite all of it by myself, so it's also a memorization exercise.
However in this case, i don't seem able to compile something that i copy-pasted; then i proceeded to rewrite it all by myself and it worked. I don't know if it's a bug or something that i'm missing.
i'll leave the code here and the terminal error. btw i'm on osx lion and i'm using textwrangler as an editor and the terminal for compiling.

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Radice
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      double r = Math.sqrt(2);
      double x = r * r;
      if (x==2)
         System.out.println("OK");
      else
         System.out.println("Non ci credevi?");

   }
}
```

￼

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Radice2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      double r = Math.sqrt(2);
      double x = r * r;
      if (x==2)
         System.out.println("OK");
      else
         System.out.println("Non ci credevi?");

   }
}
```

only Radice2 work. here's the log

```
iMac-di-alessio:~ alessiobogesso$ cd Desktop/
iMac-di-alessio:Desktop alessiobogesso$ java Radice2
Non ci credevi?
iMac-di-alessio:Desktop alessiobogesso$ javac Radice.java
Radice.java:16: error: illegal character: \65532
^
Radice.java:16: error: reached end of file while parsing
 ^
2 errors
iMac-di-alessio:Desktop alessiobogesso$
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Well, you have an illegal character in your source code.  Probably something that's not going to show up in the cut and paste.  Stuff like this happens; just delete the one that doesn't work and be happy it was only a few lines that needed to be recreated.

Comment: It seems to be a character named [Object Replacement Character](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/65532).

Comment: What editor are you using?  Make sure it's a plain text editor.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler told you that there is a illegal character in your source code. The Unicode 65532 is not printable so it is not displayed and you are unable to see it but it is there.